# How does Conquest Mode work in Super Smash Bros. Direct?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, super-smash-bros-4

The Smash Bros. title released for the 3DS has an online Conquest Mode that allows users to pick a fighter and earn points.

There doesn't appear to be any detailed information about it. Are there rewards? What determines if you can earn points (there appears to be a cooldown after playing a few rounds)?

For instance, until October 6th there is a "battle" between Mega Man and Mario. I have 8 points from playing as Mario. Does it matter which team has the most points at the end of the period, or do any points earned get redeemed somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly there are rewards, but Nintendo hasn't detailed what exactly they are.

Simply having points isn't good enough, your character also has to win.  You can see which character is currently winning by accessing Conquest Mode on the Online menu.

You earn points in this mode by playing as one of the characters in a match where both characters are present.  For the current Conquest, that's Mario vs. Megaman.

Last I checked, Mario was in the lead.

Comment: I will hold off accepting this answer until Nintendo provides more information. There are hundreds of online sources about how Nintendo has "released more details", but those "details" only state that there exists a Conquest Mode and that you'll receive in-game gold and custom parts for use in the game (how much and based on what?).

Answer (score 0):

You participate in the event by playing as one of the characters. At the end of the time period if the Character you chose to earn points for Wins, you earn Ingame Rewards like new Moves or Trophies etc.